# How to use a Boolean value in az IF condition? (Pine Script, Version 5)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

We ask the user whether yes or no:

```
YesOrNo = input.bool(false, title="Check if Yes", inline = "01")
```

Wrong example how to make something run down depending on Yes or No:

```
if YesOrNo = true
    <SomethingWeWantToDoIfYes>
```

How to do it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two equivalent ways, since it is a boolean we can just use :

```
if YesOrNo
    <SomethingWeWantToDoIfYes>
```

or explicitly

```
if YesOrNo == true
    <SomethingWeWantToDoIfYes>
```

The opposite can be done like so

```
if not YesOrNo
    <SomethingWeWantToDoIfYes>

if YesOrNo == false
    <SomethingWeWantToDoIfYes>
```